# Spring OpenSessionInViewInterceptor doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, spring, lazy-loading

I had the (in)famous problem with hibernate and lazy loading when views are rendered.... As many say, the only two solutions are:

- Make the method transactional (and this is not always desiderable)
- Use OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.

The latter is preferable IMO. Anyway I'm not sure if this interceptor is firing at all (in fact I get the same Lazy loading exception and nothing changes):

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.beans.Listino.prodotti, no session or session was closed
```

I'm using simple annotation based url mappings, so reading the docs for Spring 3, I'm using this in my servlet-context.xml:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <!-- <property name="order" value="2" /> -->
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="openSessionInViewInterceptorInst" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Which should make the trick. But it is not working and I get the exception. How do I make sure my interceptor is firing? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you using the @RequestMapping annotation? If I remember right there was an issue with putting the interceptor on the url bean. With Spring 3.0 you can define the interceptor like this:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

assuming that sessionFactory is a reference to your SessionFactory bean.

You will also need to include the mvc namespace.

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
```

Comment: Your incantation works, thanks. Anyway, for the future, how do I make sure an interceptor is firing and my config is correct? Otherwise, like in this situations, there is no other way to know that other than seeing that I don't get the exception anymore. Must be a way to debug this or to log it!

Comment: @gotch4 If you turn on logging on org.springframework to DEBUG you can see it in the log file.

Comment: How do I do that precisely? Sorry, I'm a lame newbie

Comment: In your log4j.properties file do

Comment: I love you, guy! I solved "no session" issue on jsp files for long days without success and final solution was adding OSIV interceptor to webappContext.

Comment: Change `<ref local="sessionFactory" />` to `<ref bean="sessionFactory" />`. After trying this example I had this exception : `There is no ID/IDREF binding for IDREF 'sessionFactory' `. Check this post http://www.javawebdevelop.com/3544671/]

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`<mvc:interceptors>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors).

By the way, `@Transactional` is a different thing - it doesn't make your collections work in the "view". It just opens a transaction (and a session) for the annotated method (and the methods it calls)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Struts2 with Spring and Hibernate, Try to use OpenSesisonInViewFilter and assign it in web.xml