# Understanding Spring MVC configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application, and I was pretty confident I understand all the various configuration I have set up, however, in a recent exercise I have been switching over to use pure annotation based config (apart from the security configuration) and I have seen a change in the application's behavior which has made me think twice on a few points.

The main behavior change, is that it appears that my old app was running an OpenSessionInView type pattern - as several of my domain objects were lazy loading elements, but those elements could then still be accessed outside of the transactional/service layer classes (e.g. in my controllers) - having switched to annotations, this now fails as you would expect with lazy loading errors as the session is not open in my controller layer.

Below is the config I have been using - can any one explain which part of this is responsible for the OpenSessionInView type behavior my app was displaying previously?

App Context config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:cloud="http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring 
    http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring/cloudfoundry-spring-0.7.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />
    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tmm.enterprise.adapter"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tmm.enterprise.service"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tmm.enterprise.helper"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tmm.enterprise.util"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tmm.enterprise.repository"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tmm.enterprise.core.dao"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tmm.enterprise.security.dao"></context:component-scan>


    <!--Http client -->
    <bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
        <property name="state" ref="httpState" />
    </bean>

    <!--Http state -->
    <bean id="httpState" factory-bean="httpStateFactory" factory-method="buildState"/> 

    <!--Http client -->
    <bean id="httpClientFactory"
        class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="httpClient" />
    </bean>

    <!--RestTemplate -->
    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        lazy-init="default" autowire="default">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>    


    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="applicationController" class="com.tmm.enterprise.service.ApplicationService"></bean>

    <bean id="socialConfig"
        class="com.tmm.enterprise.configuration.SocialConfiguration"></bean>
    <bean id="cachingConfig"
        class="com.tmm.enterprise.configuration.CachingConfiguration"></bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="geocoder" class="com.google.code.geocoder.Geocoder" />

    <bean id="validatorFactory" class="javax.validation.Validation"
        factory-method="buildDefaultValidatorFactory" />

    <bean id="validator" factory-bean="validatorFactory"
        factory-method="getValidator" />
</beans>
```

MVC Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller annotation. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tmm.enterprise.controller" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <!-- Turns on support for mapping requests to Spring MVC @Controller methods
         Also registers default Formatters and Validators for use across all @Controllers -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resouces/**" location="/styles, /images, /javascript, /libs" />

    <!-- a higher value meaning greater in terms of sorting.  -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" p:order="3">
        <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- register "global" interceptor beans to apply to all registered HandlerMappings -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="lang"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- selects a static view for rendering without the need for an explicit controller -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/login"/>
    <!--mvc:view-controller path="/index"/-->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/uncaughtException"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/resourceNotFound"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/dataAccessFailure"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/jobs" view-name="jobsPage"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/applications" view-name="jobsPage"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/users" view-name="usersPage"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/companies" view-name="companiesPage"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/tos" view-name="tos"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/about" view-name="about"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/privacypolicy" view-name="privacyPolicy"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/sitemap.xml" view-name="sitemap"/>

    <!-- Resolves logical view names returned by Controllers to Tiles; a view
         name to resolve is treated as the name of a tiles definition -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.js.ajax.AjaxUrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configures the Tiles layout system -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
                <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Resolves localized messages*.properties and application.properties files in the application to allow for internationalization. 
        The messages*.properties files translate Roo generated messages which are part of the admin interface, the application.properties
        resource bundle localizes all application specific messages such as entity names and menu items. -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/application" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>

    <!-- store preferred language configuration in a cookie -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale"/> 

    <!-- resolves localized <theme_name>.properties files in the classpath to allow for theme support -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource" id="themeSource"/>

    <!-- store preferred theme configuration in a cookie -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver" id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard"/>

    <!-- This bean resolves specific types of exceptions to corresponding logical - view names for error views. 
         The default behaviour of DispatcherServlet - is to propagate all exceptions to the servlet container: 
         this will happen - here with all other types of exceptions. -->
    <bean class="com.tmm.enterprise.controller.exception.NerdExceptionHandler" p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
                <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
                <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
                <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- Controllers --> 
    <bean id="connectController" class="com.tmm.enterprise.controller.ConnectController"></bean>

    <!-- allows for integration of file upload functionality -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" id="multipartResolver"/>

    <bean id="ajaxViewResolver"
        class="com.tmm.enterprise.views.AjaxViewResolver">
        <property name="ajaxView">
            <bean class="com.tmm.enterprise.views.AjaxView" />
        </property>
        <property name="ajaxPrefix" value="ajax_"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="editableViewResolver"
        class="com.tmm.enterprise.views.EditableViewResolver">
        <property name="editableView">
            <bean class="com.tmm.enterprise.views.EditableView" />
        </property>
        <property name="editablePrefix" value="editable_"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenSessionInView(Hibernate)/OpenEntityManagerInView(JPA) behaviour is often part of a filter defined in web.xml, but can also be done using an interceptor, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992855/1998186).  You can use the OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor for JPA.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: aghhh - being an idiot again then.. had gone through every detail of those two config files and was sure there wasn't anything opening the session in view filter there.. had completely overlooked my web.xml config!

Comment: So I still have the config setup in my web.xml file - do you know why that config might be being ignored now I have switched the other configs over to pure annotations?

Comment: Ah. You've also switched to JPA, so the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter / Interceptor will be what you need

Comment: I didn't actually make the switch to JPA, and it is actually using OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter already.. any other ideas?

Comment: Ok, I finally got to the bottom of it - it was related to the problem you linked to - I was only loading each configuration (web convig/persistence config) once, but I had put the @ComponentScan annotation on both of them with the base package name rather than making sure they only scan relevant packages - meaning both configs scanned and picked up all the persistence stuff.